# Ranking Values in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

What I would like to do is look at all values for "water" and rank them lowest to highest by adding a new key:value in.

However if the value of water is the same as another I want to assign it the same rank.

So far I have this, which works in that it orders then assigns rank, but I am unsure how I can check the other values to see if it the same. If it is the same I guess I would just assign 'index' instead of 'index + 1'

```
var results = {
    schedules: [
        { water: 10326.11, milk: 231.27, cola: 171.85 },
        { water: 10326.11, milk: 231.27, cola: 171.85 },
        { water: 1500, milk: 231.27, cola: 171.85 }
    ]
};

results = _(_.sortBy(results.schedules, "water")).forEach(function (water,    index) {
water.waterRank = index + 1;
});

console.log(results);
```

[Js Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qL4kps2r/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the previous value and previous index, check if the value is repeating and then assign index. Something like this

```
var index = 0, prevValue = 0;
_(_.sortBy(results.schedules, "water")).forEach(function (water, i) {
    if(prevValue != water.water) index++;
    prevValue = water.water;
    results.schedules[i].waterRank = index;
});
console.log(results.schedules);
```

```js
var results = {
  "schedules": [{
    "water": 10326.11,
    "milk": 231.27,
    "cola": 171.85
  }, {
    "water": 10326.11,
    "milk": 231.27,
    "cola": 171.85
  }, {
    "water": 1500,
    "milk": 231.27,
    "cola": 171.85
  }, {
    "water": 1500,
    "milk": 231.27,
    "cola": 171.85
  }, {
    "water": 10500,
    "milk": 231.27,
    "cola": 171.85
  }, {
    "water": 10500,
    "milk": 231.27,
    "cola": 171.85
  }]
};

var index = 0,
  prevValue = 0;
_(_.sortBy(results.schedules, "water")).forEach(function(water, i) {
  if (prevValue != water.water) index++;
  prevValue = water.water;
  results.schedules[i].waterRank = index;
});
console.log(results.schedules);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.2.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have chosen this answer it as it assigns the values back to the array! Thank you! And thanks for keeping it lodash :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

```
var rankings = _(results.schedules)
    .pluck('water')
    .uniq()
    .sortBy()
    .value();

_.map(results.schedules, function(item) {
    return _.defaults({
        waterRank: _.indexOf(rankings, item.water) + 1
    }, item);
});
```

The first step is to build the `rankings` array. The trick here, is [uniq()](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq) removes duplicate values, so any items that are *tied* with other items, will share the same ranking.

Then, you just of to map the items to the rankings using [indexOf()](https://lodash.com/docs#indexOf) to get the actual ranking value.